# If $f:G\rightarrow H$ is a homomorphism of group and $N\triangleleft G$...

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have a question about the following result.

> If $f:G\rightarrow H$ is a homomorphism of group and $N\triangleleft G$ such that $N\subseteq \ker(f)$, then exists a  unique homomorphism $P:G/N\rightarrow H$ such that $P(a+n)=f(a)$ for all $a\in G$, $\DeclareMathOperator{\Im}{Im}\Im(P)=\Im(f)$ and $\ker(P)=\ker(f)/N$.
>
> Moreover, $P$ is an isomorphism if and only if $f$ is an epimorphism and $N=\ker(P)$.

My question is, how I can prove $P$ is an injective function, I prove the other implications, but I cannot prove $P$ is injective.

Comment: And I guess lassies also answer…

Comment: Do you mean $P(aN)$ instead of $P(a+n)$?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

If you've proved $\ker P=\ker f/N$, you know a homomorphism is injectivve if and only if its kernel is $0$.